# MVVMCross (WP8, Android, iPhone) + Azure Mobile Service

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, azure-mobile-services

I need to create an app for WP8, Android and iPhone that uses the Azure Mobile Service. I am really impressed by the MvvmCross project so I really want to use it.

Before starting I have some questions:

- Can I add the AMS SDK to the .Core project and will it work for all platforms?
- Is the a easy way to handle the login views for the authentication providers on the different platforms?
- I am a little bit confused by the profiles, which one should I use?

I would really appreciate if anyone can answer my questions,
Michi

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I add the AMS SDK to the .Core project and will it work for all platforms?
```

The Core project is a Portable Class Library. 
If you want to use Azure Mobile Service SDK in it, it means you need to add it as a reference to the Core PCL, which means the AMS SDK needs to be a PCL also.

Further more, if you need it for all platforms (Windows Store, Phone, iOS, Android) this means the AMS PCL needs to have an implementation which works on all these platforms.

Looking to https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services, it looks like the **PCL is ony for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.**

There is however a **Xamarin component for Azure Mobile Services**, but it's not a PCL (if you download it and check it, there's a separate DLL for Android and iOS):

http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-ios-get-started/

If you want to have a portable functionality in the Core to be used by the view-models, what you can do is define an service interface like IMyAMSClientService in the Core and have it implemented on each platform (you implement MyAMSClientService on each platform, in the app project). You will need to think about a mechanism to handle the AMS functionality in an unified way.

> Is the a easy way to handle the login views for the authentication
>   providers on the different platforms?

Like I said above, you can have something like an IMyAMSClientService in the Core. The actual implementation of it will be on each platform and it will do the calls to the AMS SDK.

> I am a little bit confused by the profiles, which one should I use?

I assume you refer to PCL profiles?
You don't need to use anymore any hacks to get the Xamarin profiles available when you create a PCL. Did you try to create a PCL? The Xamarin profiles should be there. You need to have Xamarin installed though.